# JPages plugin disable animations on setup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

Is there a way to disable animations in Options setup?

Here is the basic setup:

```
$("div.holder").jPages({
    containerID : "itemContainer"
});
```

I'd like to disable all animations in one case and leave animations as it is in another case. Basicaly I'd like to setup JPages by 2 different ways:

1) Basic setup

```
$("div.holder").jPages({
     containerID : "itemContainer"
  });
```

2) Setup without animations. Something like this:

```
 $("div.holder").jPages({
    containerID : "itemContainer",
    animation:none,
    jqueryanimation:none
  });
```

I'd appretiate the other way of disabling animations too!

Maybe adding some empty animations css class and use css animations than?

Or some other way?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div.holder").jPages({
containerID : "itemContainer",
animation:"none",
jqueryanimation:"none"
});
```

Did you try animation:"none" instead of animation:none ? It works for me.